# React js - Is there any other way to optimize my conditional code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello is there any way to optimize my code that consist of condition statements?

Here is my code:

```
if (num === 'NUM_1') newNum = 'number1';
if (num === 'NUM_5') newNum = 'number5';
if (num === 'NUM_7') newNum = 'number7';
if (num === 'NUM_11') newNum = 'number11';
if (num === 'NUM_15') newNum = 'number15';
```

I am having a hard time thinking how to optimize this.

Thanks in advance for the help and suggestion.

Comment: maybe use `switch`?

Comment: If the pattern is consistent, you could look at using regex to do a string replace

Answer (score 2):

You can use object lookup to solve this problem:

```js
const map = {
    NUM_1: 'number1',
    NUM_5: 'number5',
    NUM_7: 'number7',
    NUM_11: 'number11',
    NUM_15: 'number15',
};

newNum = map[num] || 'unknown';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `lookup`:

```
const map = {
  'NUM_1': 'number1',
  'NUM_5': 'number5',
  'NUM_7': 'number7',
  'NUM_11': 'number11',
  'NUM_15': 'number15'
};

var newNum = map[num];
```

or a `switch` statement:

```
switch(num) {
   case 'NUM_1':
      newNum = 'number1'
      break;
   case 'NUM_5':
      newNum = 'number5'
      break;
   ...
}
```

Or use a `regex` expression like this:

```
newNum = num.replace('NUM_','number') + (/\d{1}/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

I think your are doing something about mapping keys to values.[Hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is suitable for the situation.
object is a hash-map like data struct in javascript.

### Advantages

1. More readable
2. More efficient, the time complexity of hash map is O(1).

### Origin Answer

```
const NUMS_MAP = {
  NUM_1: "number1",
  NUM_5: "number5",
  // ... other maps
}
const newNum = NUMS_MAP[num];
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation? I get how this code code be adapted and is a good answer but on first glance it doesn't look like it answers the question because it only includes 2 of the 5 cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a lookup:

```js
const map = {
  'NUM_1': 'number1',
  'NUM_5': 'number5',
  'NUM_7': 'number7',
  'NUM_11': 'number11',
  'NUM_15': 'number15'
};

var newnum = map[num];
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to mapping key to values in an object, you could also look at the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) data structure:

```
const map = new Map([
  ['NUM_1', 'number1'],
  ['NUM_5', 'number5'],
  ['NUM_7', 'number7'],
  ['NUM_11', 'number11'],
  ['NUM_15', 'number15']
]);

const newNum = map.get(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to optimise. Based on the code provided, the lookup method is perhaps the best one for you, but as an alternative you could look at regex (depending on your use-case).

If you have a static number of possibly inputs, and your pattern is potentially inconsistent (e.g. if `NUM_14` for some inexplicable reasons needed to relate to `foo` rather than following the pattern of equaling `number14`) then a lookup is perhaps the way to go. E.g. to borrow from Hao Wu's answer:

```
let map = {
  NUM_1: 'number1',
  NUM_5: 'number5',
  NUM_7: 'number7',
  NUM_11: 'number11',
  NUM_15: 'number15',
};

let newNum = map[num] || undefined;
```

Alternatively, you may find that you don't have a fixed number of keys (for example, you may have an indeterminate number of possible nums as `NUM_1, NUM_2, ... NUM_N`) at which point an alternative approach (assuming the pattern of changing `NUM_N` to `numberN` is consistent) could be to use regex and do a string replace, like so:

```
// Convert NUM_N to numberN
function format(num) {
    return num.replace('_', 'ber').toLowerCase();
}

// Test
let num = 'NUM_1';
let newNum = format(num);

console.log(newNum); // -> number1
```